What movie is this about a killer?
I saw this movie very young so I have little memory of it. It may be from the 80's or 70's, in color. I just remember that there was a young man that was a contract killer or something and he was very cold and unconcerned when he killed people and begins seeing a girl that he likes, and eventually there is a moment when some people is trying to kill him and he deals with them in front of the girl and has to confess her that he is a killer.
I'd like to see it, so if you know something I'd really appreciate it.

could you please give some more info as name of the lead actor or villain or anything such it will be helpful.

I can think of several movies which fit this description. Was it an american or asian movie? How does the killer and the girl look like?

My confidence in this one is too low to make it an Answer, but Prizzi's Honor? Jack Nicholson, Kathleen Turner, 1985?

While newer than the 70s/80s, I think you may be referring to Grosse Pointe Blank (1997), in which a hitman goes back to his home town of Grosse Pointe for a high school reunion, and reexamines his life. He does confess about his job to his love interest, because she catches him bloody after a fight with another hitman, and later has another scene confessing about his past to her that occurs during an extended gunfight scene.




Funny enough, Wiki says it's an 80's revival-themed (aka retro themed) film. The movie does revolve around a reunion for the class of 1986.

@cde yep, it is full of 80s music and references.

Ohh, I like that movie! But it's not the one I'm looking for, it's older that Gross pointe blank. I think it was an american movie, I remembered a scene where the guy and the girl are watching a movie and I think (I don't remember this part clearly) he hears a sound outside, he steps out a shots a guy in the bushes and returns to see the movie, and then when he confess he is a killer is because someone tries to kill him in front of the girl and he kills them. I'm 29 and I must have seen it when I was 10 year old or less.

I don't know the name of the actors or remember well how they looked because I was very young and never saw the movie again.

Is it possible this movie is a little newer than you realise seeing as you where around 10 in 1995. The movie I'm describing differs a small amount in details however as you said you where unsure I'd like to put      forward the following:     A very    cold and unconcerned almost blasé     handsome young hitman who is great at his work meets a nice lovey girl around his age. They begin dating and are watching TV on the couch. The next night they are at her house on the couch when they hear a noise outside. It turns out to be girlfriends ex, hitman goes and talks to ex hits ex with butt of pistol and solicits dating advice from the ex then hitman goes back inside, this scene ends with a shot of ex in the bushes as per your comments. The next night after making love hitman confesses his career choice... break up ensues.       Later on girlfriend comes to terms with his job    . This is an American movie from 1995 I watched around 1997. Its called COLDBLOODED and stars Jason Priestley. 
